# I want to Arrange Structure in C++.By their Marks with their other attribute as well.

Tags: c++

I have created a structure of Students have attributes of Name and Number.
I want to arrange them by Numbers (Top to down).What Should I do?
Please tell me without using any library.

Comment: You should sort them

Comment: `std::sort` would do. Or you could use any of the sorting techniques.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :)

Comment: make an object of your structure and access the number attributes then apply selection sort or any sort on it

Comment: Bubble sort is the easiest algorithm to implement (it's rubbish though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 struct student{
     char name[20];
     int number;
    }tmp;

    int main(){
        int size=5;
        struct student s1[size];
        // your input loop code goes here //

            for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
                for(int j=1 ; j<size ; j++){
                    if(s1[i].number>s1[j].number){
                        tmp=s1[i];
                        s1[i]=s1[j];
                        s1[j]=tmp;
                    }
                }
            }

        // your output loop code goes here //
        return 0;
    }
```

Modify it according to your variable names and insert input/output code as per your requirements

Comment: This Program is running correctly.But When I display this program number are sorted but why name don't sort with them?

Comment: you mentioned in the question that you want to sort it by numbers, and since it is an object sorting is apply on single attributes and rest attributes are swap accordingly